# Why the actions become slower after clicking on multiple link with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python and Selenium in order to download some files on a web page. The page is composed of about 10 links to click on for downloading a file. It takes less than 1 second to click on the first links but then, it takes about 5 seconds to click on the other link. So, why Selenium become slower over time? Any ideas or solutions, please? I thought about memory issue but after 2-3 clicks on links, I've got this issue. It's quite weird.

My methodology is very simple: I find all elements to click on (stored in a list) and then with a for-loop I click on each element of this list. I measure the time of each iteration and display it.

(partial code)

```py
elems = driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('Download (')
    for elem in elems:
        start_time = time.time() #start time-counter
        elem.click() #click on each element
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time #stop time-counter
        print(str(elem.text) + ' = ' + str(elapsed_time)) #display time
```

Here the results of my code:

> 1. Download (1,608 KB) = 0.03755545616149902
> 2. Download (1,373 KB) = 0.21751904487609863
> 3. Download (864 KB) = 0.2306530475616455
> 4. Download (759 KB) = 5.218845844268799
> 5. Download (841 KB) = 5.249175071716309
> 6. Download (792 KB) = 5.259352922439575
> 7. Download (711 KB) = 5.227159023284912
> 8. Download (684 KB) = 5.270978689193726
> 9. Download (708 KB) = 5.2504565715789795
> 10. Download (547 KB) = 5.232625484466553

So each line represents an iteration. We can see, that the 3 firsts clicks take less than 1 second and after that, a click takes 5 seconds.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You're doing them all at once. Starting 10 downloads at once is gonna end in a bit of a bottleneck. Try waiting one second after each print before clicking the next one and see if that clears it up.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I got the same results.

Comment: Aw. Are you running your webdriver in headless mode? I get decently improved performance with that enabled.

Comment: I tried both modes, same results again...

Comment: The site may have identified you as a bot and are throttling your requests, which is their right. You could run this script in parallel and download them all at the same time but that might not be any faster either.